# If $W$ is a subset of $V$ having property P, and no subset of W (other than W) has property P, must $V-W$ have property P?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be an undirected graph with vertex set $V$. We say that a subset $U$ of $V$ has property $P$ if each vertex of $V$ is either contained in $U$ or is adjacent to a vertex in $U$.
>   (i) Suppose $G$ has no isolated vertices. If $W$ is a subset of $V$ having property $P$, and no subset of $W$ (other than $W$) has property $P$, must $V-W$ have property $P$?
>   (ii) Repeat (i) without the condition that G has no isolated vertices.

What does *each vertex of V is either contained in $U$ or is adjacent to a vertex in $U$*? Does it mean that all vertices are preserved for the subgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer with reference to a simple graph:

[image: Simple six-node graph]

The statement is about subsets $U$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. For example, the set $\{1,4\}$ has property $P$ because every vertex is either in that set, or is adjacent to one of the two vertices in that set. However, the set $\{3,5\}$ does not have property $P$, because vertex $6$ (not in that set) is not adjacent to either $3$ or $5$.

In the original problem, it might be tempting to answer "no" to part (i), because if we choose $W$ to be $\{1,4,5,6\}$ then obviously $W$ has property $P$ but $V-W$ (that is, $\{2,3\}$) does not. However, this wouldn't fit the conditions of the problem - although $W$ does have property $P$, the subset $\{1,4\}$ of $W$ also has property $P$.

Now, you didn't ask directly for help on the original problem, so I won't pursue that directly, but I'd approach it by assuming that there exists a $W$ with property $P$ so that $V - W$ does not have property $P$ and then showing that this implies that there is a proper subset of $W$ that also has property $P$.

For part (ii), if $W$ has property $P$, then $W$ must contain all isolated vertices. Therefore, if $G$ has any isolated vertices, $V-W$ cannot have property $P$.

---

Okay, explicitly, a proof of (i):

Assume to the contrary that we have a subset $W$ of $V$ that has property $P$, that no proper subset of $W$ has property $P$, and that $V-W$ does *not* have property $P$.

Then, since $V-W$ does not have property $P$ there must be some vertex $x$ of $G$ such that $x$ is not in $V-W$ but also $x$ is not adjacent to anything in $V-W$. Since $x$ is not in $V-W$, then we know $x \in W$. Likewise, we know that $x$ is not adjacent to any elements of $V-W$. Also, since (in part (i) of the problem) $G$ has no isolated vertices, we know that $x$ is adjacent to at least one other vertex in $W$. (that is, we know that $x$ isn't isolated)

Now, all vertexes in $V$ are either the node $x$, in $V-W$, or in $W-\{x\}$. We've just shown that $x$ is adjacent to a node in $W$ that isn't $x$ itself (that is, $x$ is adjacent to some node in $W-\{x\}$). Any node in $V-W$ must be adjacent to some node in $W$ because $W$ has property $P$, but we know that a node in $V-W$ can't be adjacent to $x$; therefore, any node in $V-W$ must be adjacent to some node in $W-\{x\}$. Therefore $W-\{x\}$ has property $P$.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: How to pick a subset so that its proper subsets do not share the property $P$?

Comment: I wouldn't approach the problem so that you need to. Instead, approach it as a proof by contradiction, and assume that you have a W that has property P, but no subset does, and that V-W does not have property P. Then use that to show that there's a vertex in W that you can remove such that the resulting $W-\{x\}$ still has property P. (This provides your contradiction)

Comment: I can't seem to make a sound proof. If there is some $x$ in $W$ but not in $V-W$, then $x$ has property $P$. Is it a contradiction because $x$ should not have property $P$?

Comment: First off, $P$ is something that applies to sets of nodes, not to individual nodes. So it isn't that $x$ has property $P$, but rather that $W-\{x\}$ has property $P$, which contradicts the condition that no subset of W has property P. Give me a few minutes and I'll update the answer with a proof.